# Empty Twin Prime Sets

Tags: number-theory, induction, twin-primes

Consider this set of numbers:

$$1, 5, 8, 11, 13, 31, 37, 53, 61, 73, 79, 97, 122, 127$$

This is the set of numbers $n$ such that $nm \pm 1$ is not a twin prime pair for all $m \leq n$.

For instance, $8$ is in this list because none of these are twin prime pairs:

$8*1 \pm 1 = (7,9)$

$8*2 \pm 1 = (15,17)$

$8*3 \pm 1 = (23,25)$

$8*4 \pm 1 = (31,33)$

$8*5 \pm 1 = (39,41)$

$8*6 \pm 1 = (47,49)$

$8*7 \pm 1 = (55,57)$

$8*8 \pm 1 = (63,65)$

This list seems to end abruptly at $127$. I've checked up to $10,000$ with this Mathematica code:

```
tps[a_,b_]:=ParallelTable[
Pick[n,Length@Intersection[
Select[n* Times@@@Subsets[Table[k,{k,1,n}],{1}]-1,PrimeQ]+1,
Select[n* Times@@@Subsets[Table[k,{k,1,n}],{1}]+1,PrimeQ]-1]
==0]
,{n,a,b}]

AbsoluteTiming@tps[1,10000]

(*{266.427,{1,5,8,11,13,31,37,53,61,73,79,97,122,127}}*)
```

Is this the end of the sequence?

How could I show this to be the end of the sequence, perhaps using some form of mathematical induction?

Comment: It is not known whether or not there are finitely many Twin Primes...if there are no Twin Primes $>N$, say, then every $n>N$ would give an element of your set.

Comment: If you work heuristically on the conjectured distribution of twin primes given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brun%27s_theorem#Further_results), one gets that the "probability" of a given $x$ being a twin prime should be around $\frac{C}{\log(x)^2}$. The "probability" of a given $n$ not being in your sequence is then $\prod_{m=1}^n1-\frac{C}{\log(mn)}$. If one takes the sum of these probabilities to get the expected number of such $n$, one finds that it is finite, so it is reasonable to conjecture that this sequence is finite.

Comment: I ran your code up to 100,000 and nothing extra.

Comment: @IanMiller Thanks, running on my Raspberry Pi is a little slow...

Comment: @MiloBrandt Thanks, this is the kind of response I was hoping to get. It's well beyond what my undergrad math ed training covered.

Comment: Tested up to 100.000.000 and nothing extra